# Errors after installing '@babel/preset-env'

Tags: react-native, npm

when I was trying to start my npm project I got the following error:

```
/home/projects/reactive-weather/reactive-weather/app/node_modules/expo/src/Location.js: 
Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env' from '/home/projects/reactive-weather/reactive-weather/app'
```

Surely I need to install this module but after I did, I'm getting this error:

```
    Error: /home/projects/reactive-weather/reactive-weather/app/node_modules/expo/src/Location.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (9:5)

   7 | const LocationEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.ExponentLocation);
   8 |
>  9 | type ProviderStatus = {
     |      ^
  10 |   locationServicesEnabled: boolean,
  11 |   gpsAvailable: ?boolean,
  12 |   networkAvailable: ?boolean,
10:43:44 AM: Failed building JavaScript bundle
```

Everything was perfectly fine, the last thing I've done before this happened was using git commands like: git stash also I had to perform npm audit fix but I don't think any libs were vulnerable.

Comment: Please include the error message as (formatted) text, not as reference to an image.